# Android AlarmManager with BroadcastReceiver and Service not starting

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to start a service scheduled for a specific date. My problem is that the intent which should start the service, doesn't do it.

**This is my Helper which should start the service**

```
public class AlarmHelper {

public static void createAlarm(Context ctx, TRANSAZIONE_MENSILE tm) {
    int giorniDifferenza = calcolaGiorni(tm.getMonthDay());
    int secondiDifferenza = calcolaSecondi();
    int minutiDifferenza = calcolaMinuti();
    int oreDifferenza = calcolaOre();

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmService.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("secondi", secondiDifferenza);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("minuti", minutiDifferenza);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("ore", oreDifferenza);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("giorni", giorniDifferenza);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("requestCode", tm.getRequestCode());
    ctx.startService(alarmIntent);
}
//other methods not relevant in the process
}
```

**And here is the AlarmService**

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

Alarm alarm = new Alarm();

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    int sec = extras.getInt("secondi");
    int min = extras.getInt("minuti");
    int hour = extras.getInt("ore");
    int days = extras.getInt("giorni");
    int requestCode = extras.getInt("requestCode");

    alarm.setAlarm(this, sec, min, hour, days, requestCode);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

**And finally this is the BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int SECS = 1000;
private static final int MINS = 60000;
private static final int HOURS = 3600000;
private static final int DAYS = 86400000;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    //qui metto il codice
    //todo codice
    //prendo il request code
    int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra("requestCode", -1);
    if (requestCode != -1) {
        // cancello l'allarme che si sa mai
        cancelAlarm(ctx, requestCode);
        // ora bisogna anche che la transazione sia salvata
        AlarmHelper.resolveAlarm(ctx, requestCode);
        // ora ricreo l'allarme nuovo per il mese prossimo
        AlarmHelper.restartAlarm(ctx, requestCode);
    }
    wl.release();
}

public void setAlarm(Context ctx, int sec, int min, int hours, int days, int requestCode) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Alarm.class);
    i.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, requestCode, i, 0);
    int tempoInMilli = 0;
    tempoInMilli += (SECS * sec);
    tempoInMilli += (MINS * min);
    tempoInMilli += (HOURS * hours);
    tempoInMilli += (DAYS * days);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), tempoInMilli, pi);
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context, int requestCode) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
}
```

The Intent simply doesn't reach the service, how should I fix it? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where is your `onReceive()` calling `createAlarm()`? Why not just use `PendingIntent.getService()` instead of going through the broadcast receiver at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks for replying. the onReceive is in the broadcastreceiver. Which is the difference between using or not the receiver? my alarms should go monthly indefinitely, it will still works?

Comment: Right: I just didn't see anywhere in `onReceive()` that calls `AlarmHelper.createAlarm()` - only calls to `resolveAlarm()` and `restartAlarm()`

Comment: And there's no reason to go through a BroadcastReceiver if you just want to start a service from an alarm - they both work

Comment: @ianhanniballake true, il will add it! But my problem is before it, in debug the onReceive is never called. Anyway without using the broadcastreceiver how should I do?